# Set value of one field as the default value of another field in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table and I need to fill password column with national_id value if password column were empty on insert query.

Is there any way using trigger or something like this in mysql ?

thanks in advance

Comment: yes! using triggers! you get your own Answer !

Comment: [Yes, you use triggers for that.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use before insert, trigger:

**Trigger structure:**

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE INSERT
   ON table_name
   [ FOR EACH ROW ]

DECLARE
   -- variable declarations

BEGIN
   -- trigger code

EXCEPTION
   WHEN ...
   -- exception handling

END;
```

**Check  [Using Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) for more information**

---

**More/less detailed example**

something like this should work

DISCLAIMER : I DIDNT TEST THIS CODE and must be completed

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.password is null THEN
            SET NEW.password = NEW.national_id
        END IF;
    END;
```

Comment: would you suggest me any trigger code for what you said ??
I wrote an AFTER INSERT TRIGGER like this
`UPDATE std_personal SET password = (SELECT std_personal.national_id FROM std_personal ORDER BY id DESC limit 1 )`
trigger had no error but it didn't work

Comment: i didnt know what did u comment.... that isnt a trigger at all... take a look on my edition

Comment: @masoud Has helped you? or you still need an answer?